# Facebook Login Page - CSS is undefined

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

I recently started getting a javascript error when I go to the Facebook login page.

Line 5: CSS is not definfed.  It shows up in Firebug and every other browser's error console.

It doesn't bother my regular browsing, but I am working on a project that embeds an IE window to login to FB, and that window is popping up a javascript warning, which is not good.

I though maybe it was a temporary bug, but it's been there for a week now.  Does anyone else see this error in their browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filled up a bug report a few hours ago on that problem:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/135806113206481

Comment: Looks like they got around to fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

yes this error appearing every time I log on facebook with fire fox browser.
\To correct this error

```
* Edit the name of the CLASS called to match the selector of a CSS style already defined.

  - or -
* Add a new CSS style whose selector matches the name of the class called.
```